# $H^1(G_{K_v}, M^D) \cong \widehat{H^1(G_{K_v}, M)}$, Tate dual and Pontryagin dual

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, duality-theorems, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a number field and $G_K$ the absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $M$ be a **finite** $G_K$-module.

The Tate dual of $M$ is defined as follows: $M^D = \text{Hom}(M, \mu(K))$, where $\mu(K)$ is the group of all roots of unity.

Let $v$ be a fixed place of $K$.

It is well-known that $H^1(G_{K_v}, M^D) \cong \widehat{H^1(G_{K_v}, M)}$, where $\widehat{H^1(G_{K_v}, M)}$ is the Pontryagin dual of $H^1(G_{K_v}, M)$ (cf. Milne, Arithmetic Duality, Chap. $I, 2$).We call this sometimes Tate local duality.

My question is: Does this isomorphism hold when $M$ is **not finite**?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried studying what happens when $M=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: For comvenient, let $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and fix a prime number $p$. Then $M^D\cong \text{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Is $A=H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p}, \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$  and $B=\widehat{H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},\Bbb{Z})}$ isomorphic ? I think this cannot happened because $A$ is finite and $B$ is infinite group.

Comment: @Aphelli $A$  is finite because it is a finite Selmer group of a field, as you kindly taught me before. However, I don't have an explanation for why $B$ is infinite.

Comment: You have misread the definition of $M^D$. With the correct definition, Milne already states the result for finitely generated modules, see e.g. Corollary 2.3.

Comment: @Alex B. Coates and Sujata's 'Galois cohomology of elliptic curves' adapts this definition.If we extend the definition of the question, does it become Milne's definition, and at the same time, is it understood that M can be extended from finite to finitely generated?

Comment: @Alex B. WIkipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Tate_duality also defines the tate dual of module  as the same in this question.

Comment: @Pont: no, you misread the definition in Wikipedia. For instance, it makes the Tate dual of $\mu_3$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) zero…

Comment: @Pont: I'm afraid I don't understand your comments. If $M$ has order coprime to $\mu(K)$, then according to your definition $M^D=0$, and the claim is clearly false. E.g. any cyclic $M$ with trivial action gives a counterexample if $M^D=0$.

Comment: As an aside: the statement itself is purely local, so there is no reason to start with a number field. The number field plays no role here.

Comment: By $M^D$, do you mean the roots of unity in $\overline{K}$,  @Alex B.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you'll learn very quickly when it comes to duality theorems in Galois cohomology that that there are about a million things called duality, all slightly different from each other.

First, let's be clear on the definitions. Let $K$ be a local field and $K^s$ its separable closure. Let $G_K=\text{Gal}(K^s/K)$ be its absolute Galois group.

For a *finite* $G_K$ module $M$, define $M^D=\hom_{ab}(M,\mu(K^s))$. Note that we are taking the morphisms to the Galois module of all roots of unity, not just the ones in $K$. It is in this setting only that we have a canonical isomorphism

$$H^1(G_K,M)\simeq \widehat{H^1(G_K,M^D)}$$

I claim this does not hold for finitely generated modules $M$. Let $M=\mathbb{Z}$ have trivial action. Then $M^D=\hom_{ab}(\mathbb{Z},\mu(K^s))\simeq\mu(K^s)$.

First, we compute $H^1(G_K,M)$. Since $G_K\simeq\varprojlim\text{Gal}(L/K)$, we have

$$H^1(G_K,M)\simeq \varinjlim H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K),\mathbb{Z})\simeq \varinjlim \hom(\text{Gal}(L/K),\mathbb{Z})\simeq \varinjlim 0=0.$$

Now we compute $H^1(G_K,M^D)$. Note that $M^D\simeq\mu(K_S)\simeq\varinjlim \mu_n(K_S)$. So by proposition 1.5.1 of *Cohomology of Number Fields* (or because direct limits are exact) we have

$$H^1(G_K,M^D)\simeq \varinjlim H^1(G_K,\mu_n(K^S))$$

By Kummer theory, we know that $H^1(G_K,\mu_n(K^S))\simeq K^\times/(K^\times)^n$. So we have

$$H^1(G_K,M^D)\simeq \varinjlim K^\times/(K^\times)^n\simeq \varinjlim K^\times \otimes (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\simeq K^\times \otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.$$

Therefore $H^1(G_K,M)\not \simeq \widehat{H^1(G_K,M^D)}$.

---

There is, however, a duality theorem that does apply to finitely generated modules. For a discrete finitely generated $G_K$ module $M$. In this case, we define $M^d=\hom_{ab}(M,(K^s)^\times)$ (Note that Milne also uses $M^D$ here, but I am using $M^d$ for clarity). This case becomes more complicated because some topology enters the picture, but we obtain isomorphisms

$$H^1(G_K,M)\simeq \widehat{H^1(G_K,M^d)}.$$

Note that this recovers the duality for finite modules as a special case: Let $M$ be a finite $G_K$ module. Since a homomorphism cannot take a finite order element to an infinite order element, we have

$$M^d=\hom_{ab}(M,(K^s)^\times)=\hom_{ab}(M,\mu(K^s))=M^D.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. By the way, where can I study the proof of this duality in the case $M$ is finitely generated ? Is it included in  'Cohomology of number fields' ?

Comment: Yeah, that's where I learned it from. It's in Chapter 7 sections 1-2, which builds on the content of Chapter 3 sections 1-3 and most of Chapters 1 and 2.